# Redis-py HINCRBY to increase a field value in hash

Tags: python, hash, redis

I'm trying to populate Redis with data from CSV file in Python as below:

```
r = redis.Redis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)
with open('.../countries_list.csv') as csvfile:
    csv_reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile, delimiter =',', fieldnames = ['country', 'capital', 'population'])
    for row in csv_reader:
        country = row['country']
        capital = row['capital']
        population = row['population']
        for row in csv_reader:
            country = row['country']
            capital = row['capital']
            population = (int(row['population']))
            r.hmset(country, {'capital': capital, 'population': population})
```

That's piece of code seems to be working fine. However, I would like now to increment the value of 'population' field for each country for which 'population' = 0. (change it from 0 to 1)
I'm trying to use HINCRBY function and use simple for loop, but it does not change value in the database.

```
for row in csv_reader:
            if population < 1:
                r.hincrby('country', 'population', 1)
```

Could you please help and advise what is done wrong? And how can I filter values in the most efficient way and actually increase them? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using 'country' as a string not a variable.

```
for row in csv_reader:
            if population < 1:
                r.hincrby(country, 'population', 1)
```